# How to get the image resource of images added dynamically onto Android?

Tags: android, image

I am a little bit stuck up. First, I'll post the screenshot and then ask my question.

[image: Output]

---

You can see that some ovals are checked. What I did was maintain 2 sets of images and when the user clicks, the the white image becomes the black. 
Now, I need to collect the answers from this answer sheet and want to know how. I tried a method called `getImageResource()` but that doesn't exist. Please help me how to go about.

**Code:**

```
 public class QuizActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
RelativeLayout r2;
// Global variable(s)
int[][] quizData; // Storing the quiz specifications in an integer array
int[][] questionImages = {
        { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
                R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f, R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h,
                R.drawable.i, R.drawable.j },
        { R.drawable.a_checked, R.drawable.b_checked, R.drawable.c_checked,
                R.drawable.d_checked, R.drawable.e_checked,
                R.drawable.f_checked, R.drawable.g_checked,
                R.drawable.h_checked, R.drawable.i_checked,
                R.drawable.j_checked },
        { R.drawable.zero, R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,
                R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five,
                R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven, R.drawable.eight,
                R.drawable.nine, R.drawable.decimal },
        { R.drawable.zero_checked, R.drawable.one_checked,
                R.drawable.two_checked, R.drawable.three_checked,
                R.drawable.four_checked, R.drawable.five_checked,
                R.drawable.six_checked, R.drawable.seven_checked,
                R.drawable.eight_checked, R.drawable.nine_checked,
                R.drawable.decimal_checked } };

// End
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Beginning of variable declarations
    ScrollView s1 = new ScrollView(this);
    RelativeLayout r1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
    r2 = r1;
    File quizSpecs = new File("mnt/sdcard/teacher_1.csv"); // Read the file
    BufferedReader csvReader = null;
    String line = ""; // Storing each line in a string
    StringTokenizer currentLine = null;
    int noOfQuestions = 0; // Number of questions in the quiz
    int time = 0; // Duration of the quiz
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; // Loop variables
    int previd = 0;
    // End of variable declarations

    try {
        csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(quizSpecs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        line = csvReader.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    currentLine = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
    noOfQuestions = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
    time = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
    // System.out.println(noOfQuestions + " " + time);
    while (currentLine.hasMoreTokens()) {
        currentLine.nextToken();
    }
    quizData = new int[noOfQuestions][6];
    for (i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++) {
        try {
            line = csvReader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentLine = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            quizData[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.nextToken());
            // System.out.println(quizData[i][j]);
        }
    }
    try {
        csvReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++) {
        TextView questionNo = new TextView(this);
        questionNo.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        questionNo.setId(1000 * (i + 1));
        questionNo.setTextSize(18);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, previd);
        previd = (1000 * (i + 1));
        questionNo.setLayoutParams(p1);
        r1.addView(questionNo, p1);
        switch (quizData[i][1]) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            for (j = 0; j < quizData[i][2]; j++) {
                ImageView option = new ImageView(this);
                option.setImageResource(questionImages[0][j]);
                option.setId((1000 * (i + 1)) + j + 1);
                option.setOnClickListener(this);
                /*
                 * if (j >= quizData[i][2]) {
                 * option.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 * option.setEnabled(false); }
                 */
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ((1000 * i) + 1));
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                        ((1000 * (i + 1)) + j));
                previd = ((1000 * (i + 1)) + j);
                option.setLayoutParams(params);
                r1.addView(option, params);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            for (j = 0; j < (quizData[i][3] == 0 ? quizData[i][2]
                    + quizData[i][3] : quizData[i][2] + quizData[i][3] + 1); j++) {
                for (k = 10; k > -1; k--) {
                    ImageView num = new ImageView(this);
                    num.setImageResource(questionImages[2][10 - k]);
                    num.setId((1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * j) + k + 1);
                    num.setOnClickListener(this);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    if (j == 0) {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                                (1000 * (i + 1)));
                    } else {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                                (1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * (j - 1)) + k + 1);
                    }
                    if (k == 10) {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, (1000 * i) + 1);
                    } else {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                                ((1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * j) + k + 2));
                    }
                    num.setLayoutParams(params);
                    r1.addView(num, params);
                }
            }
            previd = (1000 * (i + 1)) + 1;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
            for (j = quizData[i][2] - 1; j > -1; j--) {
                for (k = 0; k < quizData[i][3]; k++) {
                    ImageView match = new ImageView(this);
                    match.setImageResource(questionImages[0][k]);
                    match.setId((1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * j) + k + 1);
                    match.setOnClickListener(this);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    if (k == 0) {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                                (1000 * (i + 1)));
                    } else {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                                (1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * j) + k);
                    }
                    if (j == quizData[i][2] - 1) {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, (1000 * i) + 1);
                    } else {
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                                (1000 * (i + 1)) + (100 * (j + 1)) + k + 1);
                    }
                    match.setLayoutParams(params);
                    r1.addView(match, params);
                }
            }
            previd = (1000 * (i + 1)) + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    s1.addView(r1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    this.setContentView(s1);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Beginning of variable declarations
    int clickedButton = v.getId();
    int questionNo = clickedButton / 1000; // Finding the question number
    int i = 0; // Loop variable
    int rowNo = (clickedButton / 100) % 10;
    // System.out.println(questionNo);
    // System.out.println(quizData[questionNo - 1][1]);
    switch (quizData[questionNo - 1][1]) {
    case 1:
        for (i = 0; i < quizData[questionNo - 1][2]; i++) {
            ImageView option = new ImageView(this);
            option.setImageResource(questionImages[0][i]);
            option.setId((1000 * questionNo) + i + 1);
            option.setOnClickListener(this);
            /*
             * if (i >= quizData[questionNo - 1][2]) {
             * option.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             * option.setEnabled(false); }
             */
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                    ((1000 * (questionNo - 1)) + 1));
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                    ((1000 * questionNo) + i));
            option.setLayoutParams(params);
            r2.addView(option, params);
        }
        ImageView option = new ImageView(this);
        option.setImageResource(questionImages[1][(clickedButton % 10) - 1]);
        option.setId((1000 * questionNo) + (clickedButton % 10));
        option.setOnClickListener(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                ((1000 * (questionNo - 1)) + 1));
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, ((1000 * questionNo)
                + (clickedButton % 10) - 1));
        option.setLayoutParams(params);
        r2.addView(option, params);
        break;
    case 2:
        ImageView checked = new ImageView(this);
        checked.setImageResource(questionImages[1][(clickedButton % 10) - 1]);
        checked.setId((1000 * questionNo) + (clickedButton % 10));
        checked.setOnClickListener(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_checked = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params_checked.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                ((1000 * (questionNo - 1)) + 1));
        params_checked.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                ((1000 * questionNo) + (clickedButton % 10) - 1));
        checked.setLayoutParams(params_checked);
        r2.addView(checked, params_checked);
        break;
    case 3:
        for (i = 10; i > -1; i--) {
            ImageView num = new ImageView(this);
            num.setImageResource(questionImages[2][10 - i]);
            num.setId((1000 * questionNo) + (100 * rowNo) + i + 1);
            num.setOnClickListener(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_num = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (rowNo == 0) {
                params_num.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                        (1000 * questionNo));
            } else {
                params_num.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                        (1000 * questionNo) + (100 * (rowNo - 1)) + i + 1);
            }
            if (i == 10) {
                params_num.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                        (1000 * (questionNo - 1)) + 1);
            } else {
                params_num.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                        ((1000 * questionNo) + (100 * rowNo) + i + 2));
            }
            num.setLayoutParams(params_num);
            r2.addView(num, params_num);
        }
        ImageView num = new ImageView(this);
        num.setImageResource(questionImages[3][11 - (clickedButton % 100)]);
        num.setId((1000 * questionNo) + (100 * rowNo)
                + (clickedButton % 100));
        num.setOnClickListener(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_num = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (rowNo == 0) {
            params_num
                    .addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (1000 * questionNo));
        } else {
            params_num.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (1000 * questionNo)
                    + (100 * (rowNo - 1)) + (clickedButton % 100));
        }
        if (((clickedButton % 100) - 1) == 10) {
            params_num.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                    (1000 * (questionNo - 1)) + 1);
        } else {
            params_num.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ((1000 * questionNo)
                    + (100 * rowNo) + (clickedButton % 100) + 1));
        }
        num.setLayoutParams(params_num);
        r2.addView(num, params_num);
        break;
    case 4:
        for (i = 0; i < quizData[questionNo - 1][3]; i++) {
            ImageView match = new ImageView(this);
            match.setImageResource(questionImages[0][i]);
            match.setId((1000 * questionNo) + (100 * rowNo) + i + 1);
            match.setOnClickListener(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_match = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (i == 0) {
                params_match.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                        (1000 * questionNo));
            } else {
                params_match.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                        (1000 * questionNo) + (100 * rowNo) + i);
            }
            if (rowNo == quizData[questionNo - 1][2] - 1) {
                params_match.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                        (1000 * (questionNo - 1)) + 1);
            } else {
                params_match.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                        (1000 * questionNo) + (100 * (rowNo + 1)) + i + 1);
            }
            match.setLayoutParams(params_match);
            r2.addView(match, params_match);
        }
        ImageView match = new ImageView(this);
        match.setImageResource(questionImages[1][(clickedButton % 10) - 1]);
        match.setId((1000 * questionNo) + (100 * rowNo)
                + (clickedButton % 10));
        match.setOnClickListener(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_match = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (((clickedButton % 10) - 1) == 0) {
            params_match.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                    (1000 * questionNo));
        } else {
            params_match.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                    (1000 * questionNo) + (100 * rowNo)
                            + (clickedButton % 10) - 1);
        }
        if (rowNo == quizData[questionNo - 1][2] - 1) {
            params_match.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                    (1000 * (questionNo - 1)) + 1);
        } else {
            params_match.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                    (1000 * (questionNo)) + (100 * (rowNo + 1))
                            + (clickedButton % 10));
        }
        match.setLayoutParams(params_match);
        r2.addView(match, params_match);
        break;
    case 5:
        ImageView match_checked = new ImageView(this);
        match_checked
                .setImageResource(questionImages[1][(clickedButton % 10) - 1]);
        match_checked.setId((1000 * questionNo) + (100 * rowNo)
                + (clickedButton % 10));
        match_checked.setOnClickListener(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_mc = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (((clickedButton % 10) - 1) == 0) {
            params_mc.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1000 * questionNo);
        } else {
            params_mc.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (1000 * questionNo)
                    + (100 * rowNo) + (clickedButton % 10) - 1);
        }
        if (rowNo == quizData[questionNo - 1][2] - 1) {
            params_mc.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                    (1000 * (questionNo - 1)) + 1);
        } else {
            params_mc.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, (1000 * (questionNo))
                    + (100 * (rowNo + 1)) + (clickedButton % 10));
        }
        match_checked.setLayoutParams(params_mc);
        r2.addView(match_checked, params_mc);
        System.out.println(match_checked.getDrawable());
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: sorry buddy. I can suggest to trim ur code or add comments in order to make it more readable and understandable.

Comment: is user able to select multiple answer for one question?

Comment: For some questions, he can, for some he cannot. It depends on the question specifications set in a CSV file from which I am reading.

Comment: you can use custom chcekBox with your own checked and unchecked images instead of ImageView. So you don't need to manage state of ImageView, even don't need id of images.

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava How to do that??

Comment: I can provide you selector for custom CheckBox

Comment: what does the csv file look like and can you explain the format?

Comment: A sample CSV file is like this (a bunch of numbers) - 

5,10,
1,1,3,0,3,1,
2,2,6,2,4,0,
3,3,8,0,5,2,
4,4,5,5,12,0,
5,5,4,6,1,0,

The first number is the question number. The second number is the question type. The next two are qualifier and sub-qualifier. And the next two are marks for correct and incorrect answers.

1 - Single Correct - No of options - n/a
2 - Multiple Correct - No of options - No of correct answers
3 - Integer - Digits before decimal - Digits after decimal
4 - Match the following - Items in column A - Items in column B
5 - Matrix Match - Items in column A - Items in column B

Comment: Pratyush,Welcome to StackOverflow, Please try this things before posting your code in Question 1) remove all commented lines 2) if you using eclipse select your code press ctrl+shift+f to format the code allignment ; to make your question represent the problem nicely

Comment: Can you also say,what kind of data you need to get as outcome means you definately require to submit that answer data, how the data you require to submit, because based on that developers may suggest their answers/ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @FasteKerinns. I need to collect the data and put it in a CSV file and save it on to the SD Card.

The output will be the answers selected by the user in each question.

Comment: means only one option per question like Q1-A,Q2-B this way you want data in ArrayList and then you will put them in CSV ?

Comment: Q2 can have more than option per question. With regard to the picture I put the output should be like this

1,2
2,14
3,231586.1
4,2,4,3,0,1
5,14,03

and so on

Comment: @PratyushNalam see my answer and comment for any query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of tracking the image that is currently being used, you should instead think of the problem in terms of a **Data Model**. The Data Model holds the state of the application. It looks to me like what you have is a set of questions, each question has different possible answers,and then there are the selected answer/answers. If you model the data out appropriate you can apply whatever kind of View logic you want for the state of the model. This is straight out of an MVC (Model View Controller) paradigm.

I doubt your application as it is now will scale at all and thus you should define some kind of Model, which could easily just be done with a few classes (Question class, Answer class) and you can define the relationships a few different ways.  From there you would simply write out the View based on what the current state of the model is.. In android this is done with [Adapters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) and an [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html). Typically you wouldn't use these directly and in your case you'd probably use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) with a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html).  What you will do is when the user clicks something you will capture that event, then update the model. Your ListAdapter will listen for changes to the model through a [DataSetObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#registerDataSetObserver%28android.database.DataSetObserver%29), however you could just listen for clicks and make the changes directly in the onclick listeners instead of going the full distance of having an observer.

This obviously isn't something you could likely do in an hour or two unless you were real familiar with all these things but IMO it would make your application much cleaner, easier to debug, and easier to test and more robust.

Comment: I couldn't get the need for classes here. Because all the data for each question is fetched from an outside source ie the CSV file. And this is just an answer sheet I display. This is actually one module I'm doing.

Comment: are the questions/answers always the same? There really should be an easy way for you to put this data from the CSV into a model and simply update the model.. Just because I say model doesn't mean the data lives within the app, it can come from an external source.. That is the whole point of a data model is that it can come from anywhere and your other layers of code stay the same.. Whether its a CSV file, a Database, XML, a JSON response, etc.. You just change the code which fetches the data and everything else remains the same.

Comment: My mentor doesn't want checkboxes and radio buttons. That's the problem. We have to use images like this. And all the images are inserted dynamically.

Comment: I never said you needed to use checkboxes or radio buttons but that may be a good idea (because they hold state). The tricky part about radio buttons/checkboxes is how to make some of them to have, for example, an A and another have a B or C etc? I have no idea personally and I don't think it's worth while. Just do this the right way. If you provide the csv I may give some sample code on how to do this properly if I have time.

Comment: In the way I have done, how do I detect state i.e. which image is black and which is white? I was seeing some function called setTag(). How to use that? Is it feasible in this case?

Comment: Yeah you could use that.. Set the tag to a boolean or whatever you want, then you can use getTag to get the value back.. You can use anything that extends Object

Comment: Hey Matt, I used the tag and got things off to a start. I have another problem now. I have inserted a button at the bottom to submit the answers. When the button is clicked, each of the ovals will be checked for their tag and the attempted answers should be added to an array. I used the getTag() function but it always gives output as 0 even if the tag is set to 1. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

below is the selector for CheckBox with name 'bt.xml' and put this file into your drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/chceked_image"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unchceked_image"/>

</selector>
```

and use CheckBox instead of ImageView like with name 'row.xml' in layout folder

```
<CheckBox 
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:button="@drawable/bt"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:id="@+id/ch"/>
```

button attributes change the images of Checkbox with your own images

If you will use ChcekBox, which have two state checked and un-Checked then you easily get the state of answer.

Now use layout inflater to inflate the xml, for example you have three answer for any question then,

```
 ChcekBox ch[] = new CheckBox[3];

 layout = findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

 for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
 {
   View rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, layout);
   ch[i] = (CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.ch);
   ch[i].setId(assign_new_id);
 }
```

Comment: How do I do this dynamically?